# Having trouble getting xliff tags working in my strings.xml

Tags: android, internationalization

I've read the official docs and seen what others have done on SO, but I can't get my strings to work after adding xliff tags. I have the xliff namespace imported

#### strings.xml

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<string name="string_name">
        Your goal is maintaining your levels between 
        <xliff:g id="test1" example="130">%1$d</xliff:g>
        <xliff:g id="test2" example="mg/DL">%2$s</xliff:g>and 
        <xliff:g id="test3" example="110">%3$d</xliff:g>
        <xliff:g id="test4" example="mg/DL">%4$s</xliff:g>
</string>
```

#### code

```
String raw = getString(R.string.string_name);
return String.format(raw, customGoal.getGoalValueLow(), units, customGoal.getGoalValueHigh(), units);
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have Android Studio at hand to reproduce your issue, but here is a wild guess what could be wrong:

The XLIFF standard does not list the attribute `example` for `<g>` elements (see [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#g)). Try if removing them makes a difference. XLIFF does allow you to add your own attributes, but if you do that the attribute values should start with 'x-' (see [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#Struct_Extension)).

If you want to inform the translator what the placeholders stand for you can also use the `ctype` attribute, or choose more descriptive IDs:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<string name="string_name">
        Your goal is maintaining your levels between 
        <xliff:g id="maxValue" ctype="x-number">%1$d</xliff:g>
        <xliff:g id="measurementUnit" ctype="x-unit">%2$s</xliff:g>and 
        <xliff:g id="minValue" ctype="x-number">%3$d</xliff:g>
        <xliff:g id="measurementUnit" ctype="x-unit">%2$s</xliff:g>
</string>
```